# Creating reports to show when applicants "fall off"

Tags: reporting

all.

I am hoping to build a report (series of reports?) that can help us determine where our school applicants are falling off - failing to complete a section of the application and therefore not completing. (Application is a custom object for us.)

Here's what I'd like to see:

All Contacts with required info (email, in this case). Then, a breakout into All Contacts with Required Info and application field X, but not Y or Z. All Contacts with Required Info and  application fields X and Y but not Z, and so on.

Should I be using Joined Reports for this? I'm really just looking for totals and I can't get my head around the best way to set up and filter all of this. In my mind, the best way to do this is to build all of the reports separately and then pull them into some composite report, though I don't know if that's a possibility, either.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might think in terms of using buckets as a possibility. I don't know how your data is compiled to give you a more helpful answer than that. It's really an issue of how you can "group" or combine your data.

Answer (score 1):

To do this all in one report you are going to need one field in `Application__c` that captures the "Fallout Reason".

If there aren't too many use cases, consider using a text formula field whose value is derived as (something like):

```
"Only required info", "Required Info+Step1", "Required Info + Step1-2" ...
```

Then you can easily do a report (and hence dashboard) that counts the Applications by "Fallout Reason"

If the formula field proves unworkable or you want the fallout reason to be a selectable picklist field, you'll need to use either a workflow/process builder or trigger to derive "Fallout Reason".